# Dice generator using class in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

**Update**
*Someone is probably going to drop the hammer on me for posting this way but there's not enough room in comments to cover this and they specifically tell you not to answer your own question with a follow-up, so here goes...*

I've created the dice class like you guys were talking about.

```
class dice():
    def __init__(self, sides, number):
        self.sides = sides
        self.number = number

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)
```

The `number` argument isn't doing anything though.

```
def att():
    d = dice(20, 2)
    base = d.roll()
    if base == 1:
        print 'Miss!'
    elif base == 20:
        crit = d.roll()
        if crit < 10:
            print 'Hit!'
        else:
            print 'Critical hit!\n'
            effect = super_crit()               
    else:
        print base
```

The only way I'm getting more than one die is if I do something like this:

```
def initiative():
    d = dice(10, 1)
    ini = d.roll(), d.roll()
    print ini
```

I've also tried:

```
def initiative():
    d = dice(10, 2)
    d.sides = 10
    d.number = 2
    ini = d.roll()
    print ini
```

That looks redundant to me but I get a `Type Error:` for having too few arguments without `dice(10, 2)`. No matter which method I use, I get the same result - one die. Am I missing something?

**Original post**

I'm learning how to use classes in Python 2.7 and as an exercise I'm writing a combat module for a text-based RPG. It uses the old school dice roll method to determine outcomes and effects. A roll determines a hit or miss. If a natural 20 is rolled, another roll determines if it was a critical hit. If critical hit = TRUE, another die is rolled to determined which body part is effected. Each body part is paired with a number 1-12 in a dictionary. There are three possible output messages depending on the affected part. My problem is that the entire list of values is returned instead of a specific part. What am I doing wrong here?

Yes, I know this is super nerdy. Yes, I know the output is lame, but it's all place holder.

```
import sys, random

#dice generator
class dice():
    def d4(self):
        number = random.randint(1, 4)
        return number

    def d6(self):
        number = random.randint(1, 6)
        return number

    def d10(self):
        number = random.randint(0, 9)
        return number

    def d12(self):
        number = random.randint(1, 12)
        return number

    def d20(self):
        number = random.randint(1, 20)
        return number

    def d100(self):
        number = random.randint(0, 99)
        return number 

#critical hit effect generator        
class super_crit(dice):
    def __init__(self):
        roll = dice()
        loc = roll.d12()
        hit_loc = {1 : 'Head',
                   2 : 'Left Arm',
                   3 : 'Right Arm',
                   4 : 'Left Leg',
                   5 : 'Right Leg',
                   6 : 'Left Hand',
                   7 : 'Right Hand',
                   8 : 'Left Foot',
                   9 : 'Right Foot',
                   10 : 'Chest',
                   11 : 'Stomach',
                   12 : 'Body'}
        part = hit_loc.values()
        for w in part:
            if loc <= 9:
                print w, "has been severed!"
            elif loc == 10:
                print "You sink your blade into his", w, "and pierce the heart!"
            elif loc == 11:
                print "You slash him across the", w, "and eviscerate him!"
            elif loc == 12:
                print "You shred the enemy's", w, "to ribbons!"

class attackRoll(dice):
        pass

#Attack function        
def att():
    roll = attackRoll()
    base = roll.d20()
    if base == 1:
        print 'Miss!'
    elif base == 20:
        crit = roll.d20()
        if crit < 10:
            print 'Hit!'
        else:
            effect = super_crit()               
    else:
        print base

def main():
    att()


if __name__ == '__main__':

main()
```

Comment: Side note: You've got `if base == 20:` for a natural miss, and then `elif base == 20:` for a natural hit/possible critical. Since there's no way `base` could be not 20 but also 20, none of your critical code will ever run.

Comment: Side note #2: In most old-school RPGs, a d100 treats `00` as 100, not 0, which means you probably want `random.randint(1, 100)` there (but then you may want special code somewhere later on to print "You rolled 00!" instead of "You rolled 100!"…).

Comment: PS, "I know this is super nerdy."? What's so nerdy about writing a computer program to play a text-mode game built around 30-year-old pencil&paper RPG rules in a language named after Monty Python? Or does "nerdy" means something different in English than it does in Quenya? :)

Comment: The base == 20 as a natural miss was just a typo. It's supposed to be 1 for natural miss. I altered the code to increase the probability of a critical hit so I could test the final location-based hit output without having to run the script a hundred times. I just messed up when I changed it back. Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct about the d100 thing as well. I was visualizing the 00 as 100 but thinking as a role player instead of a coder. Once again, good catch and thank you.

Comment: As for your final comment, I didn't think that far into it. I totally forgot about the Monty Python connection on top of everything else. You just upped the nerd level exponentially. That's really funny! I appreciate all your input. You gave me a good laugh.

Comment: @abarnert - You guys have given me some great tips. I'm definitely going to try that single die class that you and Travis worked out. I'll probably have to hit you two up again when I mess it up haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You loop over all the values of the dict:

```
part = hit_loc.values()
for w in part:
    # loop over each part, so print a damage message for all 12 bodyparts
```

Perhaps you meant to pick the one that is affected instead?

```
part = hit_loc[loc]  # assign *one* body part to `part`
if loc <= 9:
    print part, "has been severed!"
elif loc == 10:
    print "You sink your blade into his", part, "and pierce the heart!"
elif loc == 11:
    print "You slash him across the", part, "and eviscerate him!"
elif loc == 12:
    print "You shred the enemy's", part, "to ribbons!"
```

In other words, you do not need a loop here at all.

Note that, whenever you find yourself using a sequential series of numbers as keys to a dictionary, you may as well make it a list instead:

```
hit_loc = [
    'Head', 'Left Arm', 'Right Arm', 'Left Leg', 
    'Right Leg', 'Left Hand', 'Right Hand', 'Left Foot', 'Right Foot',
    'Chest', 'Stomach', 'Body'
]
```

except now the indexes run from 0 to 11, so use `loc - 1` to find the right body part:

```
part = hit_loc[loc - 1]
```

Comment: Great answer. For the last part, might be more readable, especially for a novice, especially in a program that's full of 1-based stuff like d12 rolls, to just do, say, `hit_loc = [ None, ` and then use `loc` instead of `loc-1`. (But on the other hand, it's probably useful for novices to get used to converting between 0-based and 1-based indexing early on. How many thousand times are you going to debug that in a typical career?)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters- Yes, that solved it. Thanks so much! I misunderstood the implementation of 'values()' and I guess I need to study the loop documentation a bit more. As I said, I'm new to all of this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

*Tangent*...

A simpler version of your dice class might be something like:

```
class Die(object):
    def __init__(self, sides = 6):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return randint(1, self.sides)
```

You now have a general purpose dice object that doesn't require you to add a new method every time you come up with a new roll mode. E.g.

```
d = Die(10);
d.roll() # ---> some value between 1 and 10
```

Adding optional `start` and `increment` attributes so that you can have a D20 that produces `5, 10, ..., 95, 100` left as an exercise to the student.

Comment: You should probably call this `Die`, since it's a since die (while his original class has a bag full of dice of difference sizes). Or, alternatively, you could have an `__init__(self, sides=6, number=1)`, so you can make a `3d6` roller, in which case maybe `Dice` is a reasonable name.

Comment: Oh, that's good stuff! I'm still very new to Python and programming in general. Abarnert and @Travis Griggs, you guys just blew my mind and saved me a boat load of time. Thanks to both of you! I'm not sure I understand the start / increment part though. I'm all for giving it a shot but I don't even know where to begin or what purpose this would serve. Care to elaborate a little?

Comment: `start` and `increment` would let you simulate a die whose sides are marked in step increments from a start value; for example, a 20-sided die where the sides are marked 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ..., 90, 95, 100.  The `start` value would be the first value, in this case `5`.  The `increment` value would be the step value, coincidentally also `5` in this case because we are stepping by 5.  The die value would be calculated as `start + (step * random_value)`.  So, if the random value went from 0 to 19, the die values would go from 5 to 100.  Probably not too useful, but fun stuff!

Comment: @steveha Ah, I get it. I'm actually pulling material from various D&D variant rules to write this code so I'm sure I could find some use for it. If nothing else, it will be a good exercise and I'll have a new trick in my bag. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a fun program for learning Python.  The other answers have mostly covered what you need, but I just wanted to point out one thing:

If you are trying to choose something in real life using dice, the way to do it is to assign numbers to the things, then roll the dice, and use the number from the dice to figure out which thing was chosen.  But, in Python, you can do things more simply than that: you can tell Python "here is a bunch of stuff, I want one item chosen at random."  The function for this is: `random.choice()`

So for the critical hit stuff, you can replace this:

```
hit_loc = {1 : 'Head',
           2 : 'Left Arm',
           3 : 'Right Arm',
           4 : 'Left Leg',
           5 : 'Right Leg',
           6 : 'Left Hand',
           7 : 'Right Hand',
           8 : 'Left Foot',
           9 : 'Right Foot',
          10 : 'Chest',
          11 : 'Stomach',
          12 : 'Body'}

# two steps to randomly choose a hit location
loc = roll.d12()
part = hit_loc[loc]
```

with this:

```
locations = ('Head', 'Left Arm', 'Right Arm', 'Left Leg', 'Right Leg',
         'Left Hand', 'Right Hand', 'Left Foot', 'Right Foot',
         'Chest', 'Stomach', 'Body')

# one step to randomly choose a hit location
part = random.choice(locations)
```

In general, when you want to figure out how to use a module like `random`, it really pays to read the documentation.  In Python, there is always some terse documentation provided with the code; from the Python prompt you can do this:

```
>> import random
>> help(random)
```

The `help()` command will print out terse documentation, and if you read through it you will find `random.choice()`, `random.shuffle()`, and other nifty stuff.

Have fun with Python!

P.S. This is a fun example program.  It's not the best example of classes, though.  You are using a class here just to get a namespace that groups related functions together, which isn't wrong, but a class is even more useful when it encapsulates some data and some functions that go together.  Here is a suggestion: make a `Person()` class, which has a member variable called `hit_points`, and write a method function `.attack()` that attacks another `Person` instance.  Then write a program that makes two `Person()` instances and has them fight each other!

I suggest it should work something like this:

```
black_knight = Person()
king_arthur = Person()

while True:
    king_arthur.attack(black_knight)
    if black_knight.hit_points <= 0:
        print "Victory is mine!"
        break
    black_knight.attack(king_arthur)
    if king_arthur.hit_points <= 0:
        print "None shall pass!"
        break
```

In this example, a `Person` instance bundles together the information about a person (hit points) and functions that work with a person (a person can `attack` another person).

You could extend the model to include critical hits; a `Person` instance could keep track of which critical hits it has received; a `Person` could have inventory, including weapons that always score a critical hit (such as "Vorpal Bunny Teeth", "Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch"), etc.

Indeed, you could keep adding more things for a `Person` to track, and more method functions, and if you kept at it you might turn the whole thing into a real game.

Comment: Wow. My head just exploded. I had all sorts of plans (and no clue how to implement them) for doing exactly what you just said. These are really great suggestions! This is all probably pretty basic stuff to you guys but it's an adventure unto itself to me. That crappy little code I wrote took me about a week. I was just trying to get the basic combat mechanics down. I hadn't even begun to try to add the character / enemy aspect yet. You have given me a lot to think about and a great starting point. I sincerely appreciate you and everyone else taking the time to help me out.

Comment: You are welcome!  :-)  And if you haven't seen the movie _Monty Python and the Holy Grail_, you really should!  :-)

Comment: Oh I've seen it about a hundred times. One of my favorites! I've been implementing the suggestions everyone has posted and it's working great. Now I'm starting to build the characters and attributes. I'll post an update soon so you can check it out. I'll probably need your help with something anyway. I'll try to sneak in some Holy Grail references. :)

Comment: Just one last tip for you: the book I used to learn python was an O'Reilly book called  _Learning Python_, by Mark Lutz.  It looks intimidatingly huge (over 1200 pages!) but it really does a great job of teaching the language.  All those pages are there to help you, not to intimidate you!  The chapters on classes should really teach you, not only how the language works, but how to use classes to help solve your problems.  Get it if you can.  The latest version is 4th edition, but if you find an older edition in a used book store, that would be fine.  http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/about-lp4e.html

Comment: Thanks! I was already thinking about getting it but I was on the fence. I have an O'Reilly Arduino book and it's great. I read the reviews people posted about their Python book and some said it was really good, others said it was horrible. It's so hard to trust those reviews though. You never know if the reviewer actually knows what he's talking about. I'll take _your_ word for it. You are obviously a trustworthy source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the for-loop over hit_loc.values(), just set `loc=hit_loc`.

There are also many other issues with the code.  Here are a few:

- Use function definitions instead of a class for *dice*
- Indent the call to *main()*
- The dictionary with number keys can be replaced with a *list* or *tuple*

Here's one possible refactoring of the first part of the code:

```
from functools import partial
from random import randint

d4 = partial(randint, 1, 4)
d6 = partial(randint, 1, 6)
d10 = partial(randint, 0, 10)
d12 = partial(randint, 1, 12)
d20 = partial(randint, 1, 20)
d100 = partial(randint, 0, 99)

def critical_hit_effect():
    locations = ('Head', 'Left Arm', 'Right Arm', 'Left Leg', 'Right Leg',
                 'Left Hand', 'Right Hand', 'Left Foot', 'Right Foot',
                 'Chest', 'Stomach', 'Body')
    roll = d12()
    if roll == 10:
        msg = "You sink your blade into his %s and pierce the heart!"
    elif roll == 11:
        msg = "You slash him across the %s and eviscerate him!"
    elif roll == 12:
        msg = "You shred the enemy's %s to ribbons!"
    else:
        msg = "%s has been severed!"
    print msg % locations[roll-1]
```

Comment: Mostly good points, but he's using `randint`, not `randrange`, and the whole point of `randint` is that you don't need to use `high+1` with it (which makes it more readable for use cases like rolling a die).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: It's true that he doesn't really need a class for this, but the whole point of the exercise was to learn how to use classes!  So for that reason, he kind of does need classes.  :-)  This makes a great example for `partial()` though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is okay to post another question when you have another question.  Since you updated your question to ask about how to do multiple dice, I am putting another answer.  (I doubt I will get any points for this, but I don't really care about the points.)

Some games need to know how the dice rolls came out.  For example, in the super-hero game *Champions*, you sometimes need to count how many six-sided dice rolled ones.  (I think... been a long time since I played.)

Anyway, instead of summing the dice and returning the sum, your dice class should return a list or tuple of dice roll results.  I will show you both.  If the tuple one is confusing, just ignore it until you know more about Python; you don't need to learn this now.

Python has a very convenient way to make a list, called a "list comprehension".  If you Google for "list comprehension" you will find many pages of explanations.  (Which is why I'm not getting any points for this... StackOverflow doesn't really need another list comprehensions explanation!)  Basically, it works like this:

`[`*expression*`for`*variable*`in`*sequence*`if`*condition*`]`

Start looking in the middle, at the "for" part.  This means "Set a variable to each member of a sequence.  Check the condition, and if it is true, evaluate the expression and append the result to the new list."

A simple example: making a list of the squares of odd numbers from 1 to 10.  This will do it:

```
lst_odd_squares = [x**2 for x in range(10) if (x % 2) == 1]
print(lst_odd_squares) # prints: [1, 9, 25, 49, 81]
```

Here is how to do this using a `for` loop:

```
lst_odd_squares = []  # start with an empty list
for x in range(10):  # just like the for part
    if (x % 2) == 1:  # just like the condition part
        lst_odd_squares.append(x**2)  # append the expression part
```

The "condition" part is optional, and this particular example could be done this way:

```
lst_odd_squares = [x**2 for x in range(1, 10, 2)]
```

Here we start the range at 1, and step by 2, so we just directly produce the numbers we wanted.

The expression usually has the `for` variable in it, but it doesn't have to:

```
counters = [0 for x in range(10)]
```

This would produce a list of 10 integers, initially all set to 0.  You could then use them as counters or something.

Anyway, here's the way to make a dice rolling class that returns a list:

```
import random

class Dice():
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self, number):
        """return a list of length number, with random values from 1 to self.sides"""
        return [random.randint(1, self.sides) for _ in range(number)]

    def roll_one(self):
        """return a single value from 1 to self.sides"""
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

d6 = Dice(6)
d10 = Dice(10)

print d6.roll(3)  # roll 3d6
print d10.roll(2)  # roll 2d10

print d10.roll(1)  # roll 1d10 -- returns a list of length 1
print d10.roll_one() # roll a single d10 -- returns a single integer
```

I changed your code a bit.  Instead of making a different class instance for each time you need to roll a different number of dice, I just made the `.roll()` method function take a `number` argument.  Your way isn't necessarily wrong, but I think this way is a little easier.

It is usually best to use upper-case letters for class names.  There is a list of rules that most Python folks like to use, called "PEP 8", and upper-case for class names is one of the rules:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

(By the way, the *Learning Python* book will give you all its examples in good PEP 8 style.  So you will learn the PEP 8 way if you learn from that book.  That's one of the ways that book teaches you all about Python.)

I used a single underscore (`_`) as the loop variable.  That is legal, and it is sometimes done as a way to signal your intention to not use that value.  We need a loop variable, but we don't actually use it, just like the `counters` example above.

Python has a "list comprehension" but doesn't have a "tuple comprehension".  So here is one way to make a tuple: first make the list, then build a tuple out of the list.

```
lst = [random.randint(1, self.sides) for _ in range(number)]
return tuple(lst)
```

You can do it all in one go, with no explicit variable name for the list:

```
return tuple([random.randint(1, self.sides) for _ in range(number)])
```

This is kind of ugly.  If we are going to build the list, why not just return it?  Why feed it into `tuple()` and then destroy it after using it that one time?

Python offers something called a "generator expression" that is sort of like a list comprehension.  The important two differences: 0) you use parentheses, not square braces; and 1) it doesn't build anything, it returns an "iterator" object that can produce a series of values.  (When Python pulls out the series of values, we say that Python is "iterating" this object.)  If you then pass this "iterator" to `tuple()`, you can directly build a tuple without first building a list and then destroying the list.  The cool trick here: you need to use parentheses to call `tuple()`, and you can just use those parentheses as the ones you need for the generator expression.

```
return tuple(random.randint(1, self.sides) for _ in range(number))
```

Again, if the generator expression stuff seems weird or hard right now, just ignore it.  The list comprehension is all you need for quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: I mostly understand what you're saying. I think my biggest issue right now isn't a lack of understanding of the various data structures as much as _when_ to use one over another or _why_ it would be more appropriate to use a `class` as opposed to a `function()`, that sort of thing. Not that I have a deep understanding of any of it, mind you, but the when and the why seem to be what hang me up the most. Anyway, I implemented your suggestion and it works great. Thanks! By the way, I ordered the book. I had an Amazon credit so I got _Learning Python_ and _Python in a Nutshell_ for $6!

Comment: I hope you like the *Learning Python* book.  As I said, that's the book I used to learn Python.  When I first started reading it, it seemed really slow, but somewhere in the second chapter or so it clicked for me and it didn't seem slow anymore.  And I really like how it not only tells you the syntax, but also some of the common idioms and tricks, and *why* people use those idioms and tricks.  And, the 4th edition covers Python 2.x, Python 3.x, and the differences.  There is some really advanced stuff at the very end of the book, but you will have mastered the basics by the time you get there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been dealing with multiple dice in the toolkit I'm building for the Pathfinder game I DM:

```
import random

def rolldice(number,sides):
    Result = []
    for dice in range(0, number):
        Result.append(random.randint(1,sides))
    return Result

class Dice():
    def __init__(self, number, sides):
        self.sides = sides
        self.number = number

    def roll(self):
        return rolldice(self.number, self.sides)

# 10th level fireball
fireball = Dice(10,6)
damage = fireball.roll()
# all of the rolls (for 4d6 drop lowest, 2d20 take highest, etc)
print (damage)
# total damage
print (sum(damage))
# a d20 roll
d20 = Dice(1,20)
print (sum(d20.roll()))
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4]
31
13
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave here some nifty Python metaclass magic I wrote. This is for you, future code archaeologist who were determined enough to dig it up from buried deep into this thread.

```
from random import randint
class MetaRoll(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, dice):
        n,n_faces = [int(part) if part else 1 for part in
                     dice.lower().strip('a').strip('_').split('d')]
        return sum( randint(1,n_faces) for i in range(n) )
class Roll(metaclass=MetaRoll):
    """ A handy RPG styled dice roller.

    The implementation has been enchanted using Python __getattr__ and metaclass
    magic. Beyond that, only the random module is used.
    enchanted using Python __getattr__ and metaclass magic. 

    As a result, any roll is exposed as a public attribute and the dice
    roller that can be used like this:

    ``Roll.a_2D6 + 2``

    Note that the ``a_`` is needed to allow names starting with numbers, and, 
    e.g. ``2D10`` is written as ``a_2D10`` or ``a2D10``.

    Attributes:
        a_3D6 (int): Rolls three six sided dice and returns the sum. This is
                      most boring example with a nice probability distribution.
        D6 (int): If there is just one die, the attribute name does not start
                   with a number. Hence, the ``a_`` prefix can be omitted.
    """
    pass


print(Roll.D6) # Outputs an integer between [1,6]
print(Roll.D20+2) # Note how easy it is to add modifiers
print(Roll.a_3d6-2) # Outputs a sum of random integers from a range [1,16].
```

ps. You know you are a wizard when describing what you've done takes longer than writing the code.